# A propriedade 'database' não existe no tipo 'typeof import...'

Tags: react, typescript, firebase

Estou tentando fazer uma conexão do meu firebase no meu projeto react com typescript, mas quando eu coloco a autenticação, aparece que essa propriedade não existe no tipo typeof ...

Meu código está assim:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/database';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_DATABASE_URL,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.REACT_APP_APP_ID
  };

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const database = firebase.database();
```

E quando eu tento compilar, essa mensagem de erro aparece

```
A propriedade 'database' não existe no tipo 'typeof import("C:/Users/user/projetos/mission reactjs/letmeask/node_modules/firebase/app/dist/app/index")'.ts(2339)
```

Alguém sabe o por quê?

Answer (score -2):

Troque os imports por:

```
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getDatabase } from 'firebase/database';
```

Agora é só fazer a troca das constantes

```
export const auth = getAuth();
export const database = getDatabase();
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).